# Fermat cubic hypersurfaces over finite fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, finite-fields, projective-geometry

Consider the Fermat cubic
$$
X = \{x_0^3+\dots +x_n^3 = 0\}\subset\mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{F}_{q}}
$$
over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_{q}$ with $q$ elements.

If $q \equiv 2 \mod 3$ then the projection $\pi:X\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{n-1}_{\mathbb{F}_{q}}$ defined by $\pi(x_0,\dots,x_n) = (x_0,\dots,x_{n-1})$ yields a bijection $X(\mathbb{F}_{q})\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{n-1}_{\mathbb{F}_{q}}(\mathbb{F}_{q})$ so that the number of $\mathbb{F}_{q}$-points of $X$ is $\frac{q^n-1}{q-1}$.

Does there exist a formula for the number of $\mathbb{F}_{q}$-points of $X$ when $q \not\equiv 2 \mod 3$?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Weil conjectures? There is such a formula for every variety (over $\mathbf F_p$, or over $\mathbf Z$ if you want to allow powers of different primes), but determining it is not always easy. It will be more complicated than for $\mathbf P^n$ because the cohomology of $X$ is not of Tate type. I imagine this problem is probably studied somewhere, but I'm not familiar with that part of the literature.

Comment: I am not familiar with the Weil conjectures at all. But if I got you comment right it is hard to derive a simple formula from the general formula you are talking about.

Comment: It's a bit of a misnomer, the Weil conjectures, because they have been theorems since 1970s. But the answer below indicates that using their full strength is probably overkill (it is exactly this type of example that led Weil to his conjectures). That said, this is the modern language in which people talk about these sort of results (if you call 1970s modern), so it's still worthwhile picking up a bit of this theory if you can.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A. Weil, in "Numbers of solutions of equations in finite fields" (Bull. Am. Math. Soc. 55, 497-508 (1949)), proved that the number of $\mathbb{F}_q$-points when $q\equiv 1 \bmod 3$ is
$$\frac{q^n-1}{q-1} +\frac{1}{q-1} \sum_{\chi_0,\ldots,\chi_n} J_0(\chi_0,\ldots,\chi_n)$$
where the sum is over $(n+1)$-tuples of non-trivial characters $\chi_i \colon \mathbb{F}_q^{\times} \to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ of order $3$ such that $\prod_i \chi_i$ is trivial. Here $J_0$ is the Jacobi sum
$$J_0(\chi_0,\ldots,\chi_n):=\sum_{t_0+\ldots+t_n=0} \prod_i \chi_i(t_i).$$
($\chi_i(0)$ is defined to be $0$.) The Jacobi sum is expressible as
$$\frac{q-1}{q}\prod_i g(\chi_i)$$
where $g$ is the Gauss sum $g(\chi_i)=\sum_{t \in \mathbb{F}_q^{\times}}\chi_i(t)e^{\frac{2\pi i}{p}\mathrm{Tr}(t)}$. In particular,
$$|J_0(\chi_0,\ldots,\chi_n)|=(q-1)q^{\frac{n+1}{2}-1}.$$
In fact Weil studied more general diagonal hypersurfaces and his results inspired him to formulate his famous conjectures. See also Chapters 8 and 10 in Ireland and Rosen's book "A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory" (particularly Theorem 2 in Chapter 10).

Finally, if $q \equiv 0 \bmod 3$ then the number of $\mathbb{F}_q$-points is like in the $q \equiv 2 \bmod 3$ case, since the equation reads $(x_0+\ldots+x_n)^3=0$.

*Addendum:* When $q \equiv 1 \bmod 3$, the total contribution of the Jacobi sums is $O(q^{\frac{n-1}{2}}q^n)$ which is exponentially smaller then the main term $(q^n-1)/(q-1)$ as long as $q \neq 4$. But for $q=4$ this is quite useless. However, for $q=4$, $x_i^3$ is either $1$ (if $x_i \neq 0$) or $0$ (if $x_i=0$) so one can parametrize the points as tuples $(x_0,\ldots,x_n)$ (up to a multiplicative scalar) where the number of non-zero entries is even. This leads by the binomial theorem to the formula $$\frac{4^{n+1}+(-2)^{n+1}-2}{6}.$$
It can also be derived by computing the Gauss sums explicitly.